# How to set a Key Listener for File Name (text Field) in JFileChooser

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser

I'm developing a `Text Editor` application that has a `JFileChooser` to save the files. I need to set the File extensions according to the selected `Files of Type` in `JFileChooser`.

eg:- **When I select  Java file Extension** (Which I have created and set as a File Filter in `JFileChooser`) **the File name should be replace with** *".java"*

**Or I should be able to append the** *".java"* **if I have already Typed a File Name** (eg: `MyFirst`); **then the File Name should be updated to `MyFirst.java`**

- All these processors have to be process before I click on the `Save Button`
- I have tried many things to listen to the changes take place in the Text field which is allowed to type the name of the File, but nothing did work.

[Here's the picture of my Application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mwVPj.jpg)

Here's my code sample...

```
if (evt.getPropertyName().toString().contains("fileFilterChanged")) {
    if (savefile.getFileFilter().equals(filter2) && savefile.getSelectedFile().getName()==null) {
        savefile.setSelectedFile(new File(".java"));

    }else if(savefile.getFileFilter().equals(filter2) && savefile.getSelectedFile()!=null){
        String getName=savefile.getSelectedFile().getName().toString();

        savefile.setSelectedFile(new File(getName+".java"));
    }else{
        System.out.println(savefile.getSelectedFile()+"3");
    }
}else{
    System.out.println(savefile.getSelectedFile()+"4");
}
```

Comment: Check the `File` returned before saving. If it does not have a `.java` extension, add it. Easy done.

Comment: @AndrewThompson: can you please be specific by giving a code snippet?

Comment: I can, but won't. Which part is confusing you? What have you tried based on that comment?

Comment: @AndrewThompson: I don't understand what you just said. Your comment is confusing me. Why can't you help me? I'm really stuck with this problem. What do you mean by `File` ? I haven't used anything to return a `File`. I'm really confusing now that Why can't you help me when you have already can?

Comment: And how I can check the `File` returned before saving? Can I use a `Thread`? or a `Listener`?

Comment: Or may be You have not clearly understand my requirement. I need to listen to the text I'm typing in the `File Name` in `JFileChooser`...
and I need to get it BEFORE I click on `Save` button.

Comment: Can anyone please Help me??? I'm really stuck in here. I cannot understand that how can I get listen to the text I'm typing in the File Name textfield of JFileChooser...

Comment: @AndrewThompson: can you tell me how to check the `File` return...?

May be this little help of you would save my day :(

Comment: @AndrewThompson: can you atleast tell me whether I can use a Thread or something?

Comment: My suggestion was based on not doing anything until the file chooser was closed. I think trying to change what the user types when it is open, is folly.

Comment: @AndrewThompson: You know what? Did you ever have a moment in your life using Notepad++ ??? Okay, well! Please use it for a moment and try to save a file by changing the file type then you will realize what I did say. Thanks for your precious time for my folly question. Peace!